# What is the reason that Quantum Mechanics is random?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, polarization, superposition, randomness

We know quantum mechanics gives a random result when we observe a particle that's in a superposition, but why is it random? One of the explanations I've heard is that because light comes with those discrete energy packets called photons, when a photon is passing through a polarized filter, it must either all pass through or all be blocked. You can't let a fraction of the photon pass through while others are blocked. Is it correct? It seems reasonable, but I couldn't find any proper source about this statement.

Comment: This is only according to the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics. In the many-world interpretation, ALL outcomes happen, so it is in fact deterministic.

Comment: @gardenhead I'm not sure that's a very fruitful way of viewing the MWI though; even if "all outcomes happen", using loosey-goosey terminology, "in our branch we only observe one", so there is still something to be explained, no?

Comment: @JoshuaLin And wouldn't the one we observe be effectively random? (If you know how to predict that observation couldn't it be extrapolated, on a massive scale, to predict the future?)

Comment: @TCooper here's a spooky thought: in MWI our observations are random "unless they are tied to our ability to observe" : https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9709032

Comment: @gardenhead in fact, in Tegmark's paper that I link above describes exactly how "we still observe randomness under MWI", section III.A.

Comment: tl;dr: nobody knows

Comment: @gardenhead also the (I think) big gap is: why does the branching happen exactly when a measurement is performed. (And not like all the time). If you branch all the time you loose coherence.

Comment: @OrangeDog there was an answer with 10 upvotes (including mine) that said that and was taken down.  Mods, was that you?  What gives?

Comment: @gardenhead Not sure how using the MWI interpretation that it suddenly becomes deterministic. How do you know what comes next in which universe/world? Until you know that, it is not deterministic.

Comment: @stackoverblown In MWI, if the wavefunction is known at an initial time, then it is determined for all future times. We just have limited information about the initial conditions. We only have information about portion of the wavefunction that is coherent with the part we are in.

Comment: The argument that you mention is a fairly standard argument to intuitively motivate the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics, for example, see Chapter $1$ of _Lectures on Quantum Mechanics_ by G. Baym.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If it helps, it's not that the nature of the universe is random, it's that we model it *as* random in Quantum Mechanics.

There are many cases in science where we cannot model the actual behavior of a system, due to all sorts of effects like measurement errors or chaotic behaviors.  However, in many cases, we don't need to care about exactly how a system behaves.  We only need to worry about the statistical behavior of the system.

Consider this.  We are going to roll a die.  If it lands 1, 2, or 3, I give you \$1.  If it lands 4, 5, or 6, you give me \$1.  It is theoretically very difficult for you to predict whether any one roll is going to result in you giving me \$1 or me giving you \$1.  However, if we roll this die 100 times, we can start to talk about expectations.  We can start to talk about whether this die is a fair die, or if I have a weighted die.  We can model the behavior of this die using statistics.

We can do this until it becomes useful to know more.  There are famous stories of people making money on roulette using computers to predict where the ball is expected to stop.  We take some of the randomness out of the model, replacing it with knowledge about the system.

Quantum Mechanics asserts that the fundamental behavior of the world is random, and we back that up with statistical studies showing that it's impossible to distinguish the behavior of the universe from random.

That's not to say the universe *is* random.  There may be some hidden logic to it all and we find that it was deterministic after all.  However, after decades of experimentation, we're quite confident in a whole slew of ways the universe *can't* be deterministic.  We've put together experiment after experiment, like the quantum eraser, for which nobody has been able to predict the behavior of the experiment better than the randomness of QM.

Indeed, the ways the universe can be deterministic are so extraordinary that we choose to believe the universe cannot be that fantastic.  For example, there's plenty of ways for the universe to be deterministic as long as some specific information can travel instantaneously (faster than light).  As we have not observed any way to transfer information faster than light in a normal sense, we are hesitant to accept these deterministic descriptions of quantum behavior (like the Pilot Wave interpretation).

And in the end, this is all science ever does.  It can never tell us that something is truly random.  It can never tell us what something truly is.  What it tells us is that the observed behaviors of the system can be indistinguishable from those of the scientific models, and many of those models have random variables in them.

Comment: [Relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-variable_theory).

Comment: "It can never tell us that something is truly random." Sure it can - it just can't prove it empirically. But being unable to prove something has never stopped science from asserting it (whether rightly or wrongly) when enough evidence supports it. (Unless by "tell" you mean something totally different from what everybody means when they say, "Science tells us X.")

Comment: @TimothySmith I get in so much trouble by pointing out what science can and can't do, and then using informal terms when doing so! (Thanks for the catch.  The intent I was going after was more along the philosophical concept of providing knowledge... but that certainly isn't the word choice I used!)

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's about _modeling_, in any case. :)

Comment: I believe the toughest nut to crack here isn't why the universe is random, but rather why it appears to be so deterministic.  Once I tried to focus on answering that question, I realized that everything we observe was stacked upon prior observations, which in turn were stacked ultimately upon what was (perhaps) undue weight on observations to begin with.

Comment: You might be interested in the hypothesis that the universe is in fact based on cellular automata. There has been a lot of very interesting progress on this recently lead by Stephen Wolfram. Check this post https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2020/04/finally-we-may-have-a-path-to-the-fundamental-theory-of-physics-and-its-beautiful/

Comment: Re deterministic explanations not working: I believe [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcqZHYo7ONs) provides a good, accessible explanation of (one instance of) this phenomenon, which may be helpful to people less familiar with quantum theory.

Comment: -1: "That's not to say the universe is random. There may be some hidden logic to it all and we find that it was deterministic after all." You do realize that this statement applies to every principle of every science, right? One can obviously hold the philosophical position you seem to be holding that scientific theories only model the universe and say nothing about the true nature of the universe, but I think it is irrelevant here. In particular, you can refuse to explain everything by saying "But hey! the universe might be something else entirely, aye!".

Comment: @DvijD.C. When someone is asking "Why does this fundamental principle hold in our universe," I find it very helpful to frame it with a reminder that science does only model things.  It doesn't tell us the truth about the world. Quite often the "why" question was seeking a truth about the world that, so the philosophical position is useful.  Then, instead of talking about why the universe does this or that, we can talk about why humans *think* the universe does this or that.  Quite often the "why" actually was found in human thinking.

Comment: Well, while I hold my own philosophical convictions about what science does, I think it's an unhelpful answer to a physics question if one needs to explicitly appeal to one specific philosophical position on science. In some sense, useful answers and explanations in science ought to be renormalizable with respect to what deeper philosophical theory one espouses to. Edit: Sometimes such answers aren't possible and that forces us to bring what was previously deeper philosophy into the domain of concrete science, and I am perfectly happy with that.

Comment: @DvijD.C. I would enjoy seeing an answer from your position.

Answer (score 38):

As Feynman [said](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html) when laying out the first principles of quantum mechanics:

> How does it work? What is the machinery behind the law?” No one has found any machinery behind the law. No one can “explain” any more than we have just “explained.” No one will give you any deeper representation of the situation. We have no ideas about a more basic mechanism from which these results can be deduced.
>
> We do not know how to predict what would happen in a given circumstance, and we believe now that it is impossible—that the **only thing that can be predicted is the probability of different events.** It must be recognized that this is a retrenchment in our earlier ideal of understanding nature. It may be a backward step, but no one has seen a way to avoid it.

That statement in bold re probability is what @SuperCiocia is saying.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the *why* it's probabilistic (vs deterministic), which was the crux of the question.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the context of the Feynman quote, Feynman is saying that the best evidence they have suggests that it is probabilistic, but that nobody knows why. In this regard, I believe this still represents the extent of our understanding.

Comment: @Alexandre Aubrey: It does address the why.  In one sentence: that's the way the universe words, but we don't have an effing clue about WHY it works that way.

Comment: @AlexandreAubrey "We don't know why" *is* an answer to "why?". If we don't know why, what other possible answer to that question can be expected?

Answer (score 22):

It's weirder than you thought.

The wavefunction itself is fully deterministic. People often say "it's the measurements that are probabilisitic" but that isn't right either. The measurement is deterministic *if you include the measurement apparatus in the wavefunction*. And therein is the core of the great mystery, and the big philosophical questions of whether we should include *ourselves* in the wavefuncion. Mathematically speaking, we should, and that gives us the Many Worlds interpretation.

The real question is: why do I subjectively experience a probabilitic outcome? We don't have the pholosophical answers to what "I" and "experience" refer to in that sentence. Another way to put it is that the real question is *why don't I experience the whole of the wavefunction*?

If a conscious mind can (for reasons unknown) only experience one outcome of *the many which all truly do actually happen* then a probabilistic subjective experience may be the only possible experience. It then raises the question of how we associate probabilities with the wavefunction. Why is the probability proportional to the *square* of the amplitude? No one really knows, but perhaps there is a deep explanation hinted at [here](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html) although I confess I do not fully understand it myself, but again the answer may be it's a mathematical necessity.

Comment: if subjective experience is an objective thing, it exists and is experienced across all possibilities

Comment: +1 on the physics term "weirder".

Comment: If the measurement apparatus is included in the wavefunction, then a measurement has not occurred. It's not some magic properly of tools that effects an observation.

Comment: @OrangeDog sure it has, sounds like you've still got the old, misguided idea that a measurement has only one outcome :-)

Answer (score 10):

a) I wouldn't call it "random" but "probabilistic".

b) The evolution of a system is fully deterministic. It's the outcome of *measurements* that is probabilistic.

c) Your reasoning is wrong. The probabilistic nature of measurements' outcomes is something intrinsic to quantum mechanics ([the measurement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem)), independent of the specifics of the measurement apparatus.

Comment: How is "probabilistic" different from "random"? They mean the same thing to me.

Comment: @Puk Well if the state were $|\psi\rangle = (1/\sqrt{2})(|1\rangle + |2\rangle)$ I'd say the outcome is fully random because the chance of getting $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ is exactly the same. But for $|\psi\rangle \propto 0.1*|1\rangle + 0.9*|2\rangle$ then it's more probably to get $|2\rangle$. So I'd classify random as a subset of probabilistic. But it might be semantics than precise defintions.

Comment: I see. I would call both "random", with the degree of "randomness" defined by $\psi$. But yes, just a matter of semantics.

Comment: Well there is uniformly random and random in othee ways, yet it's still random.

Comment: I feel like the random/probabilistic issue isn’t really addressing the core of OP’s question. If my statement is so controversial I’ll edit part a out. Interesting discussions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143469/is-there-any-difference-between-random-and-probabilistic) and [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Are_the_terms_random_and_probabilistic_of_the_same_meaning).

Comment: You are making the common mistake of thinking random means uniform distribution.  This is wrong: the sum of two dice is most likely going to be 7 but that's still very much a random process that can be modeled by a random variable.  Random variables can have any distribution imaginable.

Comment: I think the confusion stems from "random sample" which laypeople often use interchangeably with "simple random sample" where each unit in the population has equal probability of being sampled.  Of course in reality it is common to do experiments with random samples which are weighted (polling, clinical trials, etc)

Comment: Random is probabilistic when we can see the likelihood. Without likelihood, it's just completely random.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking why QM is random (which in your case given the context is used as probabilistic), and what is correct to say is that QM is probabilistic in nature, and our underlying world, and our universe seems to us to be quantum mechanical, and truly probabilistic.

> is there a way to understand the system as having an initial state which forced it to come to this conclusion," the answer is a qualified "no": there are hidden-variable interpretations like the pilot-wave theory which interpret quantum mechanics as a deterministic theory containing unknowable global information.

The point is global. There are quantum effects that cannot be understood in classical terms.

> using some thought experiments (my favorite is a game called Betrayal) one can prove that there are quantum effects which cannot be understood in terms of classical local information

Now the universe ultimately is quantum mechanical, and probabilistic. There might be some underlying mechanism, that is not understood by us, but some specifically state that this underlying mechanism, that would make the universe seem fully deterministic to us, cannot be known. The error is not in our measuring devices, we know that we cannot learn about the underlying mechanism (even if there is one).

> In a deeper sense randomness is our way of reasoning about information that we do not know,
> whether there is some unknowable information which makes everything deterministic, it is known that we cannot (not just do not) know it.

[How do we know that certain quantum effects are random?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362866/how-do-we-know-that-certain-quantum-effects-are-random)

So the answer to your question is, that the error is not in our measuring devices, the universe looks to us truly probabilistic, and QM is the best way to describe it that best fits the experiments. QM is simply probabilistic because it describes (models) a universe that appears to us to be truly probabilistic in nature, and there is no (to our knowledge) underlying (more fundamental) mechanism.

Comment: random = probabilistic in the context given, as was explained in the other post's comments.

Comment: @kludg correct, I edited.

Answer (score 3):

**Quantum Indeterminacy is Key to the Arrow of Time**

There is no machinery to explain the randomness (as Mr. Anderson answered from Feynman), but maybe a connection to other phenomena can help.

I'm going to go out on a limb here, because answers in this forum are supposed to be from established science.  But I think I can make a case for an important explanation that I think follows logically, even if I haven't seen in the literature.

I think we can make the case that there is a fundamental connection between [quantum randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_indeterminacy) and the [arrow of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_of_time).  Here are the parts of that idea:

*Special Relativity and Time Reversal*

We know from Special Relativity that all inertial frames are equally valid, that the laws of physics in one (non-accelerating) frame are exactly the same as in any other.  This principle also applies to frames of reference where time is reversed.  In fact the [Feynman-Stueckelberg interpretation of antimatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparticle#Feynman%E2%80%93Stueckelberg_interpretation) is the idea that antimatter is matter going backwards in time.

*Time Reversal and Entropy*

But we know from the second law of thermodynamics that entropy either increases or stays the same, but it doesn't decrease (at least not on the macro scale).  So one principle says that the laws of physics are the same under time reversal (actually something called CPT) but another says that entropy increases are irreversible.

This contradiction is called [Loschmidt's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loschmidt%27s_paradox).

*Time Reversal and Quantum Choices*

Now here's the idea that I came up with.  It's probably already out there somewhere, I've looked and haven't seen it though.  If someone knows where this has been developed (if it has) I would very much like a reference.

If a sequence of events is deterministic (one with no random quantum choices) then the time reversal of that sequence must also be deterministic, and the reversal of that sequence would always return the system to its original state.

But if a sequence of events involves random quantum choices, then the reversal of that sequence also involves random quantum choices, and those choices don't have to return the system to its original state when time is rolled back to the original time.

---

**Example:**

A photon goes towards an atom, its absorbed by that atom, the atom waits a random amount of time, then it emits a photon in a random direction, and the photon moves away from that atom.

If we could start with the end of this sequence and reverse time, then we get the same kind of sequence, but the time the atom exists in an excited state doesn't depend on the original time and so is probably not going to be the same amount of time, and the direction the photon is emitted is also random, so is probably not going to be in the original direction.

---

So we can have both the rules of physics be the same between a frame going forwards in time and backwards in time, and still have the forwards and reversed sequences be different, as long as there are random quantum choices in that sequence.

So I think the resolution to Loschmidt's Paradox is this: If entropy increases in a process and so the process is irreversible, it must involve random quantum choices.  If a process is deterministic, and doesn't involve random quantum choices, then it must also be reversible and so the entropy in that system will stay the same.

Comment: Suppose two computer programs whose run state exhibits increasing entropy over time.  One program is driven by a psuedo random number generator, and the other a (allegedly) true random number generator (say based on a particle detector or some other low level quantum phenomena).  Can you tell them apart?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there are systems that actually use quantum phenomena to generate random numbers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator#Quantum_random_properties

Comment: Knowing that you knew that I said "and the other a (allegedly) true random number generator (say based on a particle detector or some other low level quantum phenomena).".   Talking about your "forward" and "reverse" ideas - suppose we talk about "ensemble of states" rather than state, where "ensemble" is the distribution of probabilities (i.e. the pdf) over the range of states at time (t).  The mapping from pdf(t) to pdf(t+delta) can itself be deterministic even though the state transition function is not.  Which is more "real" - the pdf over all states or an individual state?

Comment: And which is more important to 'life', and to 'intelligent life'?

Comment: That a pretty deep question.  I wouldn't even know where to begin to come up with an experimental question that addresses your question about ensembles versus states.  Smarter guys than me have said the ergodic hypothesis explains the number of possible microstates in the Boltzmann equation, but I suspect it's something more like the entropy difference we see between polarized photons and an unpolarized photons.

Comment: I don't think *all qm interpretations* create a non-entropic arrow of time. Some do like MWI or Cophng  but not pilot-wave or superdetermism. The (non MWI, Cophng) laws of physics are completely time symmetric, and alone they say nothing about an arrow of time (or it pointing in either direction). You need sufficient initial/prior conditons (like a low entropy big bang) *along* the physical laws to get an arrow of time. You don't need quantum randomness. Once your system is large, the laws of physics and multiplicity are sufficient for an entropic arrow

Comment: -1: It is well-understood as to how an arrow of time emerges due to statistical considerations, as explained by Boltzmann before the wake of the previous century in his H-theorem. Arrow of time is a statistical property, it has nothing to do whether your mechanics is quantum or classical. Proof: I always make my omelet classically ;)

Comment: @DVij  Loschmidt's paradox was pointed out after Boltzmann published his H-theorem, so I'm not sure why you think H-theorem would resolve it.  And if the luminaries of physics were struggling to hash out these ideas, I don't think it's that well understood.  

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-theorem#Loschmidt's_paradox

Answer (score 2):

We don't even know that the universe *is* fundamentally random. That's just the most popular interpretation *(called the [Copenhagen Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation))*.  In this interpretation, the behavior of particles is probabilistic with no deeper reasoning, and the *"why"* is left to philosophers *(or, possibly, a future Theory of Everything)*.

---

There *are* other interpretations in which the universe is not fundamentally random.  [Hidden variable interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-variable_theory) say that QM is actually deterministic, but we deal with probabilities due to not having enough information about some hidden variables.

This seems like the most logical first guess.  However, due to [Bell's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem) discovered in the 60's, we know that *any* deterministic QM interpretation must necessarily be **non-local** - that is, it requires all particles in the universe to be somehow connected to one-another, and able to communicate at faster-than-light speed.

So basically, physicists are more willing to discard determinism than discard locality.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum mechanics is random or, more accurately, probabilistic, because nature is fundamentally not deterministic. Of course there are those clinging to deterministic explanations, like Bohmian mechanics, by ignoring mathematical proofs, just as there are those clinging to Dingle's argument against relativity. But the argument "I don't understand the proof, therefore the proof is wrong" is not a valid scientific argument, even if the arguments disproving determinism are considerably harder to understand than the arguments proving that Dingle was wrong.

The Schrodinger equation may well appear deterministic, but it only determines probabilities; probabilities do not determine results. Quantum probabilities obey a different mathematical structure from classical probability theory precisely because classical probabilities are determined by unknowns or "hidden variables". The mathematical structure of quantum mechanics is as it is precisely because there are no hidden variables determining measurement results.

There are numerous mathematical proofs of this fact, starting with von Neuman (1936). Further proofs have been given by Jauch & Piron (1963), and by Gudder (1968), and many others, but they are sufficiently abstract that few physicists understand them. Kochen and Specker gave a proof which more physicist understand in 1967. Bell himself gave a proof in 1966 (but written earlier), based on work by Gleason, only Bell still didn’t understand the proof, and claimed there was something wrong with it. Bell himself gave a proof in Bell's theorem (1964), which has been generally accepted because it is directly testable in experiment, and is less abstract than other proofs, requiring only that classical probability theory is refuted by experimental evidence, which has since been obtained.

I have given deeper discussion in my second books, and two demonstrations that nature is fundamentally not deterministic in my third (see my profile for links)